# Filter Products by Catagory in Django

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have a filter list on my home page:

```
<!-- ? Filter -->
<div class="filter border-top border-bottom row">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="{% static 'store/images/bottoms.png' %}" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="{% static 'store/images/outerwear.png' %}" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="{% static 'store/images/tshirt.png' %}" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="{% static 'store/images/shoes.png' %}" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="{% static 'store/images/skateboard.png' %}" alt="">
    </a>
```

and trying to filter with something like this:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "store/home.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        catagory = catagory.objects.filter(catagory)
```

Can I pass the catagory name of the icon I click to the view to filter it? And also can I pass the filter back my home page (thats already listing all Products on) ?

This is my home view:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "store/home.html"
    context_object_name='products'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
```

Would it be easier to add the queryset to this and set the filter to all as default? Any help appreciated thank you.

Comment: It's *category*, not "catagory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your links should look something like:

```
<a href="{% url product_filter filter=bottoms %}">
    <img src="{% static 'store/images/bottoms.png' %}" alt="">
</a>

# urls.py
path(r'product/<filter>/', ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_filter')),
```

Then you would just need to catch the parameter in the View, and filter the list on that.

---

Edit: Adding response and code from question in comments for better formatting.

```
class ProductListView(ListView): 
    model = Product 
    template_name = "store/filter.html" 
    context_object_name='products' 
    ordering = ['-date_posted'] 

    def get_queryset(self): 
        return Product.objects.filter(catagory__name=self.kwargs['filter']))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!
Does this view look okay?

    `class ProductListView(ListView, filter):
    model = Product
    template_name = "store/filter.html"
    context_object_name='products'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']


    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(catagory=filter)`
Getting: TypeError at /
filter expected 2 arguments, got 0

Comment: @MatthewCasey added code to earlier answer, "filter" isn't passed in as a class, instead it's a parameter on the request, and available in `self.kwargs`. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering for more info and examples.

Comment: WORKS PERFECTLY! Thank you so much ive been stuck on this for what seems like forever!